# Button has dark line on bottom

Tags: themes, buttons

I am new to WordPress. I use it with the Backend-Builder “Avada Builder”.

I have an event calendar and have to created a button. I create the button, but it has a black/navy line at the bottom. I inspected it within the browser but have no clue. I changed several parameters (padding, margin, ...), also the opacity of surrounding elements, but the issue remains.
The “site” is a calendar event, so, is there a possibility to place the button under the calendar details? I have seen no option.

The Theme I use is Avada and Avada Child.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could try switching themes to check if the line is still there, but it sounds like it won't be and it's something in the Avada CSS that you're accidentally triggering. I still think inspect is the way to go: if you can't find which elements is triggering it you an try deleting parts of the page, or turning off CSS on nearby elements, etc.